# Save terminal output coming from bash loop command

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu, unix

I have a bash loop like this:

```
for f in *.fastq; do
echo $f
main command
done
```

I want to print anything that gets printed in my terminal (including file names and error messages) to a text file. How can I do  this? Thanks

Comment: If you just mean stdout and stderr, appending `> >(tee somefilename) 2>&1` immediately after the `done` will suffice. If you **really** mean terminal output, as in inclusive of content written directly to `/dev/tty` (which is often done *explicitly to bypass* logging or interception for security reasons), then you need to use a tool such as `script`, `screen` (with its logging options), etc.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to keep the `stdout`, `stderr` being displayed on your screen you can just after your loop redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file in **overwrite** mode or **append** mode using respectively:

```
for f in *.fastq; do
echo $f
main command
done > file.out 2>&1
```

or

```
for f in *.fastq; do
echo $f
main command
done >> file.out 2>&1
```

If you want to have at the same time both stderr, stdout displayed to your screen and saved to a file use:

```
for f in *.fastq; do
echo $f
main command
done |& tee file.out
```

or

```
for f in *.fastq; do
echo $f
main command
done |& tee -a file.out
```

where `tee -a` runs `tee` in append mode and `|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1 |`

**READINGS**:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24337/piping-stderr-vs-stdout